# remove specific characters from the filename using Python

Tags: python, file, rename

how to rename **multiple files** from a folder by deleting only the underline character?

Ex: 1_2_3.txt
To 123.txt

Comment: You'd have to find a way to list the files in a directory. Then substitute the **specific characters** with `replace()`. Finally you can use `os.rename()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use Python's `os` package

```
folder_path = "INSERT PATH TO YOUR FOLDER HERE"
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if "_" in filename:
        new_filename = filename.replace("_", "")
        os.rename(os.path.join(folder_path, filename), os.path.join(folder_path, new_filename))
```